# AngularJS URL link helper in routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, helper

When developing a large AngularJS application it is often cumbersome to write out urls to template files within application routes such as:

```
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'app/views/application/authentication/login.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
```

Is there a way to use some kind of URL helper class or utility class within Angular to shorten this to:

```
$helper.getView('application/authentication/login.html')
```

The same functionality when accessing images

```
<img src="../../../img/myimage.jpg" alt="my Image" />
```

Comment: What are you using as your backend? NodeJs?

Comment: You could define your images in a css file, then the paths are simply relative to the css file. With regard to the change in the $routeProvider, I don't understand how you would expect your function to know what url routes to that path?  If you are assuming the html file name or something you can simply write you're own function that just takes the one parameter and calls $routeProvider... but again I don't understand the point.